# How to find coordinates of a point inside selected row in DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, row, coordinates

I know that `DataGridView.HitTest` can be used to find an index of a row at a specific point, but how can I find the coordinates of a point somewhere inside a `SelectedRow` of a `DataGridView`?

Clarification: I need coordinates of a point inside `SelectedRow` without mouse click action. The row selection occurs programatically.

Comment: I think you are looking for Control.PointToScreen or Control.PointToClient

Comment: Could you expand some more details? It's very unclear what the problem is.

Comment: @bokibeg please see updated clarification

Comment: I think `dgv.GetRowDisplayRectangle` is what you need then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var rt = dgv.GetRowDisplayRectangle(rowIndex, false);`

From [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.getrowdisplayrectangle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> public Rectangle GetRowDisplayRectangle(
>       int rowIndex,
>       bool cutOverflow
>   )

It will give you exact coordinates of any given row relative to the grid's coordinates.